# Memory leak issue in deploying multiple Tomcat application in Cpanel Server

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, cpanel

We have tried to deploy multiple tomcat applications in Cpanel server and we are facing the memory issue quite often. When we are running a single tomcat application it works fine without any issues but when running two applications this causes the %CPU to increase above 250 and both the application becomes stuck. Can anyone please help us on this? Please see the error shown in log below.

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Exception in thread "http-bio-80-exec-1206" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Exception in thread "http-bio-80-exec-1195" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

#

Comment: You can try to Increase the memory capacity of the JVM

Comment: Hi,

We have add the '/usr/local/easy/bin/setenv.sh' where the memory was already increased by adding the below code.

export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m"

Comment: If your tomcat is new .Check your jsp and procedures for the existence of dead loop and deep recursion

Comment: why do you think this is a memory leak?

Comment: @LPGAD : Tomcat version is 'easy-tomcat7-7.0.42'. The first deployed application has been running fine without issues more than an year by now. But the issue started occuring when deploying multiple application.

Comment: @Scary Wombat : From the log file it seems to be a 'OutOfMemoryError' issue.

Comment: `OutOfMemoryError` != `Memory Leak`

Comment: see https://plumbr.eu/outofmemoryerror/permgen-space

Comment: I believe you are doing hot reloading; there should be a flag autodeploy=true make that false.

Comment: Second point your new web app has got memory leak... to identify it is painstakingly slow.. and time consuming

Comment: Permsize=2048 definitely points in directions of leaks. Think this way perm gen area is where you store class files (not exactly) that should not grow indefinitely unless you making inner classes on the fly or having long recursive loops ...

Comment: @harry Maybe this cPanel server doe not even have that much available memory

Comment: Hi All, Thank you the comments. 

@harry : We will need to check regarding the class part mentioned and also the 'autodeploy=true' (Cannot find the option in server.xml, Will check other options as well).

Comment: @Scary Wombat : The server is a dedicated server with only the tomcat application deployed. The memory is 16 GB RAM. The load on the server will be between (2 -3) when the issue occurs and comes down to normal( Less than 0.5 )

Comment: @SandeepSasikumar : https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html#Automatic_Application_Deployment

Answer (score 0):

You will need to tweak and optimize the server for proper resource usages and as the Java apps that you are running and running out of Memory.

what server configuration do you have ? is it a VPS or a dedicated server ?

or you are using shared hosting  ?

Comment: The server is a dedicated server with only the tomcat application deployed. The memory is 16 GB RAM.

Answer (score 0):

- Are you in production environment?
- Exception appear exactly at deployment stage or at the first usage of your app?
- Your apps are ligth (microservices) or are monolithics apps ? Xms and -Xmx arguments depend of that.

When you deploy a war file in tomcat, some section of tomcat java memory are used and is not well-managed by tomcat. A proof of that is if you deploy several times the same app without restart, an outofmemory appear in tomcat log.

If you are in production environment:

- Use one tomcat by app. So you can deploy, stop, start, restart, etc this app without risk of impact other apps. **If you restart tomcat after one deploy, memory errors at deployment stage go away.**
- Use tomcat-docker. With docker your could kill the entire tomcat ad start a new instance in each deploy. So your tomcat would be clean.